# Look at drilled down data only

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with my `VBA`.  What I am doing here is that I need to apply background color based on the sum of each row. e.g. if `sum = cellA2 then red`.

I only need to apply this conditional formatting to the drilled down data in my matrix table:

```
Sub threecf()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=$a$1")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=$a$1")
    Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=$a$1")

    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With

    With cond2
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With

    With cond3
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

---

P.S.
My question is specifically on how should I only apply my vba code on the dynamic drilled-down data. these are not fixed rows as the next refresh might increase or decrease the range of cells. e.g. below is what I mean by drilled-down data.

[View Image here on sample Drill-down data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzXcR.png)

My conditions are simple, e.g.  below is one of them. I know how to write them in excel but not in VBA. the other two will be the same logic.

[image: SKIPPING BOLD FONTS EXAMPLE]

condition1: if sum(Range("B8,D8,F8,H8,J8,L8,N8,L9,N9")) = 0 and Font.Bold = False then RED background

condition2: if sum (Range("B8,D8,F8,H8,J8,L8,N8,L9,N9")) > sum (Range("L9,N9")) and Font.Bold = False then Orange background

condition3: else and Font.Bold = False Green

**the conditions will apply to all the rows from B8:O8 down EXCEPT the header rows (which are the rows with BOLD FONTS)**

Comment: What is your issue? Any errors? What is your question (you didn't ask one)? See [ask] please. Did you try the macro recoder and appying the conditions? That should give you enough hints to write a good functional code.

Comment: You should use a formula summarizing the row. You should use something like `=Sum(2:2)=A$2`, but is should be dynamic to be applied on any range you choose. I will adapt your code and post it able to work as (I understand) you need.

Comment: How are these "Drill Downs" created?

Comment: These are created dynamically via a connection (querying db) and importing data = a select statement.

Comment: So, is **Bold** a reliable way to detect the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub threecf()
    Dim rg As Range, cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
    
    Set rg = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    With rg
        'clear any existing conditional formatting
        .FormatConditions.Delete
    
        'define the rule for each conditional format
         'define the rule for each conditional format
        Set cond1 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=SUM(" & .cells(1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "," & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 4).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 6).Address(0, 0) & ")>Sum(" & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 8).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 10).Address(0, 0) & ")")
        Set cond2 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=SUM(" & .cells(1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "," & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 4).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 6).Address(0, 0) & ")=Sum(" & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 8).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 10).Address(0, 0) & ")")
        Set cond3 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=SUM(" & .cells(1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "," & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 4).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 6).Address(0, 0) & ")<Sum(" & _
                                .cells(1).Offset(0, 8).Address(0, 0) & "," & .cells(1).Offset(0, 10).Address(0, 0) & ")")
    End With
    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With
    With cond2
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With
    With cond3
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

You did not say anything about the other two conditions, so I've chosen "=A3" and ">A3". You can easily adapt the code according to your real need, I think...

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to clarify on the drilled-down part; the code you kindly provided is still not solving my issue with the 'only drilled-down' part of my question. cheers

Comment: @Soben In order to solve 'your issue' you have to better define it. What does "sum of G2" should mean? Now I can see you changed your mind and try using different cells... Is this your last edit? I mean if the sum of C,E,G > sum of I,K...

Comment: @Soben Now, you defined **a condition**. Which to be the other two? Do you expect us to post the code and then also saying that it does not solve your issue?

Comment: @Soben Please, test the updated code. I tried imagining the other conditions, but now the code will be simple to be adapted if you have a different issue, I think...

Comment: @Soben Still doesn't it what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answers; I see your point and added to my questions. it's very complete now.

Comment: @Soben It looks that your question is "dynamic", changing continuously and tends to become a never ending story... I will try making another piece of code, but only **after** clarifying of some issues: What does "Font.Bold = False" mean? Font of which range? The range "B8,D8,F8,H8,J8,L8,N8,L9,N9" or the cell where the conditional formatting is applied? If the bigger range, should it return true if **all** cells in discussion have bolded text, or **at least** one of them?

Comment: @Soben Plese, also clarify what **else** in this string "else and Font.Bold = False" does mean. What you (say you) want is not so simple. I mean, to determine the Bolded cells Excel does not supply a function. A UDF function must be created. Conditional Formatting formulae do not accept discontinuous ranges, so a helper range, using the UDF formula must be built (somewhere on a sheet) and invoked in the conditional formatting formulae. So, I will not spend my time for something unclear. I must also confess that I am not so sure that what you wrote last time reflects your real need...

Comment: @Soben Can you explain **why** do you need such a conditional formatting? What do you need to check by using it? Should the range `Range("B8,D8,F8,H8,J8,L8,N8,L9,N9")` be relative or absolute? Do you want using the non Bolded cells to be evaluated by conditional formatted Formulae, or only to **select the cells which conditional formatting should not be applied**?

Answer (score 0):

This answer address how to identify the range to apply CF'g to.  I'm assuming you are ok with the CF code itself

You need somethig unique about the header rows you want to exclude the CF'g from.  You mention **Bold** as a possibility.

Strategy:

1. Identify the data range (based on column A as in your code).  I'd suggest Using `.End(xlUp)` to avoid stopping at any intermediate blank row)
2. Loop the range and build a new range excluding the headers.  I've used **Bold** to identify headers.  Change this If condition if you want to use some other identifying feature.
3. Remove any existing CF rules from *whole sheet*
4. Apply CF rules to identified data range
5. I notice your rule for Orange is equivalent to `sum (Range("B8,D8,F8,H8,J8,L8,N8")) > 0`
6. Explicitly set Priority and StopIfTrue properties

```vb
Sub ThreeCF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgRaw As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim cf1 As FormatCondition
    Dim cf2 As FormatCondition
    Dim cf3 As FormatCondition
    Dim f1 As String
    Dim f2 As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or specify the sheet
    With ws
        ' safer to use Up
        Set rgRaw = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    For Each cl In rgRaw
        ' Identify non-header rows.
        If Not cl.Font.Bold Then
            If rg Is Nothing Then
                Set rg = cl.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 14)
            Else
                Set rg = Application.Union(rg, cl.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 14))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Check result in immediate window
    Debug.Print rg.Address
    
    'clear any existing conditional formatting from whole sheet
    rgRaw.Worksheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    
    ' Apply your CF'g to rg
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        With rg
            
            f1 = "SUM(RC2,RC4,RC6,RC8,RC10,RC12,RC14)"
            f2 = "SUM(R[1]C12,R[1]C14)"
xlA1, xlRelRowAbsColumn, rg)
            Set cf1 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:=Application.ConvertFormula("=" & f1 & "+" & f2 & "=0", xlR1C1, xlA1, xlRelRowAbsColumn, rg))
            Set cf2 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:=Application.ConvertFormula("=" & f1 & ">0", xlR1C1, xlA1, xlRelRowAbsColumn, rg))
            Set cf3 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="TRUE")
        End With
        
        With cf1
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
            .Priority = 1
            .StopIfTrue = True
        End With
        With cf2
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            .Priority = 2
            .StopIfTrue = True
        End With
        With cf3
            .Interior.Color = vbGreen
            .Priority = 3
            .StopIfTrue = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```